# Click JS button on page load

Tags: javascript, html

I want my webpage to auto click a button when the page is loaded. This is my button:

```html
<button class="configure-product configure-product-simple elementor-button" type="button" data-price="95" data-product_id="1934">Stel samen!</button>
```

I think this button calls a JS function of a wordpress plugin, so that you open the product configurator. If i copy this button html on another page tho it wont work. It will only work on the product page.

Im very new to developing, so i could really use some help. Does anyone have any ideas how to implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("my-button").click();
}
```

```html
<button id="my-button" class="configure-product configure-product-simple elementor-button" type="button" data-price="95" data-product_id="1934">Stel samen!</button>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lit for this answer! It works 8/10 times on loading, is there any chance to make the code more stable?

Comment: Propably yes, but honestly I don't know how :/

Answer (score 2):

this is how to do it in jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){ //on document loads (you could change to window also)
  $('#click').click(); // click
})
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#click').click();
})




$('#click').click(()=>{
  console.log('thanks!');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="click"> Click Meeh </button>
```

another shorter way to do it in vanilla js

```js
document.onload = document.querySelector('#click').click();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="click" onclick="console.log('hi')"> Click Meeh </button>
```

other ways to do it

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/38517365/18001301
2. [window.onload vs document.onload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588040/window-onload-vs-document-onload)

Answer (score 2):

document.getElementById("input").click();

Comment: where's onload event?